# Difference between two theorems about limit of derivatives vs. derivative of limit.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

My question is how to have uniform convergence in first theorem.

The statement of the two theorems.

Theorem 1: Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of real valued functions on an open interval $I\in \mathbb{R}$, each having continuous derivative.  Suppose that $\{f'_n\}$ is uniformly convergent on $I$ and that for some $a\in I$ $f_n(a)$ converges.  Then $\lim_{n \to \infty}f_n$ exists, is differentiable, and $$(\lim_{n \to \infty}f_n)'=\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n'$$

Theorem 2: Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of continuously differentiable on $[a,b]$ and $f_n(x_0)$ converges for some $x_0 \in [a,b]$.  If $\{f_n'\}$ converges uniformly on $[a,b]$ , then $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly on $[a,b]$ to some function $f$ and $$f'(x)=\lim_{n \to \infty }f'_n(x)$$

Now I noticed that the first theorem does not conclude that $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly.  In the proof of Theorem I, it breaks down.

Proof (Theorem I)
By FTC $$\int_a^xf'_n(t)dt=f_n(x)-f_n(a)$$
for any $x\in I$ and any $n=1,2,3,...$. Let $\lim_{n \to \infty} f'_n=g$.  Now we know that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{x_0}^x f'_n=\int_{x_0}^x g$. 
Since $$\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(a)=f(a)$$  $$\implies \lim_{n\to \infty} (f_n(x)-f_n(a))=\int_a^x g$$ for any $x\in I$. The limit exists it is $$\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(x)=f(a)+\int_a^x g$$.  Let $f(x)= f(a)+\int_a^x g$. Cannot get uniform convergence because for $N$ large enough $|f_n(a)-f(a)|\lt \epsilon$ and for $N^*$ large enough $|f_n(x)-g(x)|\lt \epsilon$.  We choose $\max(N,N^*)=M$. So we have $$|f_n(x)-f(x)|=|f_n(a)-f(a)+\int_a^xf'_n-\int_a^xg|$$
$$\le|f_n(a)-f(a)|+\left|\int_a^xf'_n-g\right|\le \epsilon+|x-a|\epsilon$$ So we have pointwise convergence for $n\ge M$.

Is it enough to make $I$ bounded i.e $|I|\le C$ where $C\in \mathbb{R}$ so that we can do the following $|f_n(x)-g(x)|\lt \frac{\epsilon}{C}$ which would allow $$|f_n(a)-f(a)|+\left|\int_a^xf'_n-g\right|\le \epsilon+|x-a|\frac{\epsilon}{C}\le \epsilon+\epsilon$$ because $\frac{|x-a|}{C}\le 1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Difference Between Theorems.** Both theorems have the same hypotheses except that in Theorem 1 the interval is open while in Theorem 2 the interval is compact. Both theorems have the same conclusion except Theorem 1 does not have uniform convergence of $\{f_n\}$ while the Theorem 2 does.

**Answer Part 1.** The OP asks if assuming in Theorem 1 that the open interval $I$ is bounded is enough to get uniform convergence of $\{f_n\}$. The argument the OP suggests for this is correct. So the answer to that question is is yes.

**Remark.** The proof of the first theorem goes through if we only assume the $f'_n$ are integrable on any compact subinterval of $I$ rather than assuming the $f'_n$ are continuous on $I$.

**Remark.** In Theorem 1 we can conclude uniform convergence on any compact subinterval of $I$ by applying the second theorem to any such interval.

**Remark.** The hypothesis that the derivatives $f'_n$ are continuous is not necessary in the Theorem 2. See Theorem 7.17 in "Principles of Mathematical Analysis" by Rudin. See also the remark following the proof of that theorem.

**Answer Part 2.** No additional hypotheses are necessary in Theorem 1 to get uniform convergence of $\{f_n\}$ on $I$. In fact, the hypothesis that the derivatives $f'_n$ are continuous can be dropped. See Theorem 9.13 in "Mathematical Analysis" by Apostol. The proof is based on the mean value theorem rather than the fundamental theorem of calculus.